# why we use getter and setter in php?

Tags: php, setter, getter

```
//If it doesn't chech if its a normal old type setter ot getter
//Getting and setting with $this->getProperty($optional);
//Getting and setting with $this->setProperty($optional);
```

why use like this? we can use normal function .

Comment: One gets a value, one sets it?

Comment: A getter gets the value of an unaccessible field, a setter sets its value. Both combined produce a lot of useless code that makes the programmer think this is OOP. No, it's not.

Comment: This is OOP fundamentals which any decent tutorial covers pretty early on. This is not a teaching website.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A **getter** allow you to **GET** the value (to read it), and **setter** allow you to **SET** the value (to write it)

If you have a "myVariable" field in a class, to give access to this variable from outside your class, you can :

- Put the field public => free access by anyone, and thus possibility for the third parties to do anything 
  (ex: to put the variable in an incoherent state compared to the treatment that you intend to do later )
- Retain the field private, define public methods getMaVariable and setMaVariable => slightly heavier, but possibility to define a get but not the set (-> read-only), total control of the actions performed on the value of the variable : Control value non-zero), possibility to define additional actions compared to the "simple" reading or writing (ex really to the con: incrementation of a counter) ...